# Number of quotient in division

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

In division, how many quotient are there?

Let's Consider The number  $A$ as the dividend. 
The number by which we divide is called the divisor $B$. The result obtained is called the quotient $q$ . The number left over is called the remainder $r$.

For example if $A=10$ , then $q=\{1,2,3,5,10\}$ , because we have:

$10=10*1+0=2*5+0=3*3+1=4*2+2=2*5+0+6*1+4=7*1+3=8*1+2=9*1+1$

I mean, in general,  what's the $|Q|$ ? Where $Q$ is the set of possible $q$  (for number 10, $Q=\{1,2,3,5,10\}$ ).

Thanks

Comment: I'd say roughly $2\sqrt A$. You get every number from $1$ to $\sqrt A$, and then you get the quotient by every number from $1$ to $\sqrt A$.

Comment: Hi @Gerry Myerson thanks, but for 10, $2\sqrt 10 = 6.32$ and $ |Q|=5$

Comment: Do you know what "roughly" means, linkho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is tabbulated at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.](http://oeis.org/A055086) It says there that a formula is $\lfloor\sqrt{4n+1}\rfloor-1$, equivalently, $\lceil2\sqrt{n+1}\rceil-2$